# Apply CSS style depending on outcome of ternary operator

Tags: javascript, css, ternary-operator, apex

I'm looking to set the color of a font depending on the outcome of the following Apex statement. So if the statement is true or false, a different color is applied.

The output is the date, red or black. Red signifies the date is overdue, i.e: is in the past.

```
<div class="due_date">
    <apex:outputField value="{!x.Date}" styleClass="{(x.Date < TODAY()) ? 'color : #FF0000' : 'color : #000'}" />
</div>
```

Neither colors seem to be taking effect. Could someone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: What is the actual output/result of this code?

Comment: `styleClass="..."` this does not seem to do what you seem to think it does. (I echo: "what's the actual output?")

Comment: Oh, so I can't use styleClass in this way? I didn't know that... Would you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I did this.

```
     <div class="due_date">
          <span>
                <apex:outputField value="{!x.Date}" rendered="{!x.Date > TODAY()}"/>
          </span>
          <span class="overdue">
                <apex:outputField value="{!x.Date}" rendered="{!x.Date < TODAY()}"/>
          </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: What should your code be doing when `x.Date = TODAY()`?